# XQuery Update queries in BaseX are succesful, but no changes are written to the file

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-update

I am trying to use XQuery and BaseX to manage some files.xml as databases.

I am using basexclient to send queries to basexserver. For example I have a simple file called library.xml like the following:

```
<library>
   <book>gone with the wind</book>
   <book>the thornbirds</book>
</library>
```

and I would like to add a node, so from `basexclient` terminal I send:

```
XQUERY insert node <book>Dracula</book> as last into doc('library.xml')//library
```

and then I get the message

> Query executed in 10.5 ms

But nothing has changed into the file. Is there a command to commit changes?

Comment: Are you checking the original file, or the database created from it? If you created a database, changes are not automatically written to the file. Does  `doc('library.xml')` contain the changes?

Comment: Yes, I am checking the original file and it does not contain any changes. I have been reading basex documentation for days but I still have not understood how it works.

Comment: I added a [feature request to print a warning message](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1041) in such cases. BaseX really isn't friendly to (especially) new users in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performant updates to (serialized) XML files are barely possible. BaseX and also the other XML databases on the market all use [special, internal representations with indexes](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Storage_Layout) for fast querying, and especially updates.

If you **already created a database** from the file, your query updates the database, not the original XML file. You should be able to observe the changes (possibly multiple times, one node added for each attempt to run the query) in the database representation, which you can verify by running

```
doc('library.xml')
```

and checking its contents. To serialize the changes to a file, use BaseX' [`EXPORT` command](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#EXPORT).

If you **didn't create a database** yet and query a file on your hard disk, a temporary in-memory database gets created, which indeed is successfully updated - but instantly discarded. [Create a database](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Databases#Create_Databases) before running updates.

*See [Christian Grün's answer discussing the `WRITEBACK` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27316007/695343), wich enables you to update a file without creating databases.*

Answer (score 4):

By default, updates on a memory instances of your file will not be propagated back to disk. You can change this by turn the [WRITEBACK](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#WRITEBACK) option on. I agree that the behavior is surprising; it was introduced to prevent users from accidentally changing local files.

A general note: If you want to update local files, it may be better to use BaseX in standalone mode. If you are working with the client/server architecture (i.e., with `basexclient` and not `basex`), the server could have been started from a different working directory, and it may not be able to resolve the relative path in your doc() function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a simple sync service between a system and baseX.
I have a similar issue in that I'm doing multiple queries using PHP Client and making multiple queries on the same session or multiple that succeed without showing results as viewed from baseX dba. I open, execute, get results if any and close each query. 
If I execute each query separately, I get the result updated (after a refresh) in dba. 
I'm running this as a service with port 1894 open to localhost. 
Each query has the general form of

```
try {
$myXML22 = 'somegenerated xml' 
$filepathname = "mydoc/mydoc_doc22.xml";
$docID = "22";
$dbName = "myDB";
$input = 'let $xml := \''.$myXML22.'\' '.
         'return db:replace("'.$dbName.'","'.$filepathname.'",$xml)';
$query = $session->query($input);
$log .= "Updated/added $filepathname to basex db ".$dbName." \n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log("somemessage".$e->getMessage());
}
```

Here is a logging of the service.

1. Db myDB exist in baseX
2. Found 24 mydoc editions in myDB db in baseX
3. Checked manifest exists in myDB db in baseX
4. Found 5 timeStamp entries in manifest of myDB db in baseX
5. Created XML for doc22
6. Validated against RNG for doc22
7. Updated/added myxml/mydoc_doc22.xml to basex db myDB
8. Inserted timeStamp node for mydoc 22 into manifest for basex db myDB

Comment: Seems to be something to do with systemd on ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone have a basex.service example that works?